# Scrollview not resizing

Tags: android, android-layout, resize, scrollview, pinchzoom

I am using pinch zoom to just horizontaly zoom my custom view. It works fine, but the outside scroll view is not resizing with its content, and there are ugly blank space arround the view.

My Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview">
        <Auda.WaveFormView
            android:id="@+id/waveform"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="2000dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/ToolbarBackground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="62dip"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="71dip"
        android:layout_height="52dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        style="@android:style/MediaButton"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My zooming code

```
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1f / prevScale, 1f / mScale, 1, 1, 0, 0);

scaleAnimation.Duration = 0;
scaleAnimation.FillAfter = true;
this.view.StartAnimation (scaleAnimation);
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why are you using an `AbsoluteLayout` ? [It's been deprecated since API 3](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html).  You should use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) instead.

Comment: I changed it to RelativeLayout, but still got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although your view is now (for example) drawn on half of the screen, it is really still occupying the full screen. You can verify this by adding a ClickListener to the view and trying to press the blank area you marked.

To solve this, you can add an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) to your ScaleAnimation. In the [`onAnimationEnd`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd%28android.view.animation.Animation%29), simply update the LayoutParams of your Auda.WaveFormView. For example:

```
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1f / prevScale, 1f / mScale, 1, 1, 0, 0);
scaleAnimation.Duration = 0;
scaleAnimation.FillAfter = true;
this.view.StartAnimation (scaleAnimation);
//after your are done with your animation
//set the animation listener
scaleAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        //this might not be the right logic 
        //especially that you are using scales relative to prevScale
        this.view.getLayoutParams().width = v.getWidth() / mScale;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
});
```

Comment: Setting LayoutParams is not working. THe returned Width is -2 or 0 and It does not change the width of the View (the scrollbar is not resizing too)

Comment: I fixed it. use getWidth instead

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the layout width to fill_parent instead of wrap content